# Dynamically create an embedded image

Tags: apache-flex

I need to dynamically create a LinkButton with an icon. The names of files (icons) have the format `images/icon_0.png`, `images/icon_1.png`, ... `images/icon_1000.png`. But I don't know the specific image for this button. I only know the index of the icon.

I tried this, with no success:

```
var path:String = "@Embed(source='images/icon_" + imageindex + ".png')";
myButton.setStyle("icon", path);
```

I get a runtime error:

```
Type Coercion failed: 
*cannot convert "@Embed(source='images/icons/icon_427.png')" to Class*
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that will not work.

Since imageindex is a compile-time variable, then embedding tag will trigger an error message.

Why not to override the button and add extra property like 'iconPath' that will expect a string path instead of a Class object. This way you can manually set (inside extended Button) the icon.source = iconPath without having to use embed.

Answer (score 0):

pls try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        [Embed(source='icon_1.png')]
        [Bindable]
        private var linkButtonIcon:Class;


        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            lnkbutton.setStyle("icon",linkButtonIcon);

        }

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            [Embed(source='icon_2.png')]
            var linkButtonIcon2:Class;
            lnkbutton.setStyle("icon",linkButtonIcon2);

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:VGroup>
    <mx:LinkButton  label="test" id="lnkbutton"/>
    <s:Button label="change Icon" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: He wants to have dynamically set path inside the embed tag. sorry but i don;t see you using it. maybe because it does not work...